# C# table column is not showed in service based database and ado.net

Tags: c#, database, linq, ado.net

I am using `service based database` and `ado.net` framework.

Here is my table, it has 3 attributes.

[image]

But then, I can't see `nomor_nasabah` attribute in the options here:

[image]

FYI, that `nomor_nasabah` is a `foreign key` from another table.

Why is `nomor_nasabah` property not showing ? where did I go wrong ?

update :

here is my model, and there's no `include foreign key`
[image]

`tabungan` attributes are : `nomor_tabungan` , `nomor_nasabah`, `saldo`

Comment: Is there something related to `LINQ` here?

Comment: yep, it is. i want to insert the data to database using linq

Comment: This looks like Entity Framework. What version are you using? Also, check when you update your model if the "Include foreign key values" are included.

Comment: i am using C# VS 2008. how to check if my model `include foreign key values` or not ?

Comment: @Cignitor, right-click your model and look for the checkbox "include foreign key columns in the model". (that is in 5.0, your version may differ)

Comment: @gunr2171 i have edited the thread, please take a look at em

Comment: @Cignitor, look under `update model from database`

Comment: @gunr2171 is it `validate` ? or `properties` ?